# Why do I not get the same results for entropy()?

Tags: python, numpy

The documentation for `scipy.stats.entropy` says:

> If `qk` is not None, then compute the Kullback-Leibler divergence `S = sum(pk * log(pk / qk), axis=0)`.

```
print(np.sum(p * np.log(p / q), axis=0))
print(entropy(p, q))
```

However, I am getting two different values here:

```
0.510046080249
0.353272019382
```

In both cases the logarithm with base *e* should be used here. So why do I get two different results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're not normalising your `p` and `q` to 1. See below:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import entropy

p = np.asarray([1,2])
q = np.asarray([2,3])

p_norm = p/np.sum(p)
q_norm = q/np.sum(q)

print(np.sum(p_norm * np.log(p_norm / q_norm), axis=0))
print(entropy(p, q))
```

Comment: Indeed. There was a major mistake I made further up in the code! I normalized `q` wrong here!